# Is it possible to run several sessions on Nightwatch for a single test

Tags: automated-testing, nightwatchjs

I'm using the Nigthwatch framework and I was wondering if it's possible to launch several sessions in a single script. So for example, in the same test, it launches two instances of Chromedriver and so you can test interactions between two client sessions.

I have checked on their website but I haven't been able to find any information concerning that. I only saw the option to launch test in parallel but it's something totally different.

Maybe Nightwatch is not made for this purpose?
I used to do that with Selenium and Python directly but I would like to improve these multiple-sessions tests with nightwatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a discussion on the forum of Nightwatch.js,  it doesn't seem possible to run two browser sessions in the same script. So I have found a way to do what I wanted to perform by using parallel tests.

Nightwatch.js enable to run scripts in parallel. So I have written a script for each session and run them in parallel.

Problem solved ✅